# Why is JavaScript runtime included with Gradle for Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently ran a `Lint` analysis on an Android project, and I noticed some curious errors in `<mypackageroot>/.gradle/node/lib/node_modules/...` directory.

One `Lint` error is in the file called `npm-scripts.html`:

```
<code>postmyscript</code>). Scripts from dependencies can be run with `npm explore</p>
<p><pkg> -- npm run <stage>`.</p>
<h2 id="common-uses">COMMON USES</h2>
```

The error is `Element stage is not closed`. Based on the syntax, I can see the issue - but this error begs the question:

*Why JavaScript runtime is even included with `Gradle`?*

Off of the top of my head, the only use for it I can come up with is the `Instant Run` feature - as it functions similarly to how React Native apps are deployed, but I don't see it mentioned in the in-depth dives into how it actually works, [such as this](https://medium.com/google-developers/instant-run-how-does-it-work-294a1633367f). I am very curious as to what it's actually used for. Thanks!

Comment: "Why JavaScript runtime is even included with Gradle?" -- it's not, at least in general. Some dependency of your project might be doing that. For example, I seem to recall Apollo-Android requiring NodeJS, at least once upon a time.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your comment. I did a quick search, and you are correct. I put what I found in an answer so others can see. Though if you would answer the question, I will gladly accept your answer and remove mine.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research based on a comment by CommonsWare, and I did find that `appollo` (which is indeed used in the project) is using `NodeJS` for the following reason:

> node is required to run apollo-codegen tool to get intermediate
>   representation of graphql operations that will be then handled by
>   plugin.

[Source](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/1027). So it seems as though it's not actually used in Gradle directly. Props to CommonsWare for direction.